Какие есть способы удобной верстки страницы под CMS?
У многих сайтов используется CMS, в которой генерируется код страницы.
Во время вёрстки приходиться вставлять html через override в браузере, чтобы можно было посмотреть результат, но это не очень удобно, так как приходится вручную искать контейнер для вставки кода.
Открывать весь код страницы через VS Code тоже не очень удобно, т.к. в репозитории храню, только изменяемую часть внутри контейнера, а остальное не трогаю (оно генерируется само).
Вопрос:
Есть ли способ автозамены контента в контейнере страницы?
Возможно, кто-то знает расширения VS Code для верстки под CMS?
UPD:
CMS создает на странице специальный контейнер <div class="container">, куда вставляется готовая верстка, чтобы опубликовать.
Во время верстки для предпросмотра результата я использую Override в браузере, т.е. вставляю написанный код в <div class="container">. Делаю это вручную (через поиск в dev tools, затем заменой html внутри этого div). Я хочу найти способ это как-то автоматизировать.
Пока первая мысль пришла использовать iframe с указанием локального html

У Вас весьма странный способ работы с CMS

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Как редактировать вёрстку на сайте под управлением CMS?) И ищите какое-то универсальное решение, еще и расширение под VS Code, которое позволит вам менять вёрстку в любом месте сайта по взмаху ресниц?))) Каждая CMS уникальна, будто битрикс или вордпресс, две разные CMS с 2 разными способами доступа к контенту страниц. Не морочьте голову себе и другим. Работать надо с каждой CMS в отдельности, принимать все её капризы и делать по её правилам.

Скорее всего я плохо описал, поэтому никто не понимает.

Я верстаю код контента, который потом добавиться через CMS.
CMS создает на странице специальный контейнер , куда вставляется готовая верстка, чтобы опубликовать.
Во время верстки для предпросмотра результата я использую Override в браузере, т.е. вставляю написанный код в . Делаю это вручную (через поиск в dev tools, затем заменой html внутри этого div).
Я хочу найти способ это как-то автоматизировать.
Пока первая мысль пришла использовать iframe с указанием локального html

Что это за CMS такая, что для просмотра проделанной работы, нужно в браузере редактировать HTML?

CMS Theseus. У неё нет предпросмотра, потому всё что загружено появляется на проде через 2 часа.

как именно ты работаешь с cms? что конкретно ты в нее загружаешь? Как происхоДит локальная разработка?

@Meow35 эмм, ну что-то я ничего толком о ней не нашел, большинство результатов поиска по запросу "CMS Theseus" относятся к различным публикациям, размещенным на платформе Theseus, которая используется финскими университетами для публикации дипломных работ, потому сложно что-то подсказать.

@Simon, обычная headless cms - в которой данные структурированно хранятся

Не цепляйтесь, пожалуйста, за CMS. Я её упомянул, чтобы вы поняли, что верстается не вся страница, а только часть находящаяся внутри тут добавляется моя верстка. Я спрашиваю как можно VS Code заставить вставлять код на страницу сайта через override в этот самый div.

Да не нужен тебе овеерайд. Запускаешь отдельным сайтом, и пишешь скрипт, который заменяет content.

Я верстаю код контента, который потом добавиться через CMS. CMS создает на странице специальный контейнер <div class="container">, куда вставляется готовая верстка, чтобы опубликовать начнём с того что CMS переварит эту "готовую вёрстку" в обычный текст(символы< и > там заменятся на нерабочие). это наверное их главная фича и одновременно отличие от того, что в 90ых/0ых называлось "блогами". для настоящих CMS верстать нет ни нужды ни смысла. можно просто писать слегка приправляя тест BBcode'ом или MurkDown'ом. нароооод... где там притчи про ~забивание гвоздей микроскопом?

Как один из вариантов, можно через Override в *Dev Toolsна странице добавитьiframe`, а в качестве контента указать на файл с версткой.
Пример:


<div class='container'>
  <iframe src="file:///C:/Pages/test.html" width="400" height="200">
</div>



Тогда можно будет спокойно писать в test.html свою верстку, и не заменять её.
Возможно, стили для iframe нужно будет поправить.
